# Efficient substitution of stacked for-loops

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I have run into an efficiency problem when calling for arguments of a large array. My Code is:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

%%timeit
z=20
A=np.arange(-z,z+1,1)
M=list(product(A,A,A,A))
test = [i+j+n+m for i,j,n,m in M]
```

M contains arrays with 4 entries, these contain all possible combinations of the integers between -20 to 20. THe Problem is that executing these lines takes my pc around 100 to 900 ms. Is there an efficient way to generate the same array 'test', but like 100 to 1000 times faster?
Thank you for reading all this, any answer is appreciated!

Comment: For starters, simplify to `z = 20; r = range(-z, z+1); test = [i + j + n + m for i in r for j in r for n in r for m in r]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer veedrac. Unfortunately your method takes even longer to calculate the array.

Comment: Can you get away with using a generator?